# Onclick Call From Jquery Cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is is possible to get the onclick command to execute two commands? I would like the onclick command for the first image to execute not only a link to another page but also a mailto command. Can I do this with a function? If so, how should the onclick call the function and where should the function be placed?

**Here is a snippet of the code:**

```
document.write('<div id="JQCycle1" class="JQslideshow center-JQS" style="width: 180px; height: 150px;">');

document.write('<img src="JQuery-Cycle/set1/image1.jpg" alt="Image 1" width="180" height="150" onclick="javascript:location.href=\'http://bilbowdish.ipage.com/gulfdriveband/index.html\'" style="cursor:pointer;">');
// document.write('<img src="JQuery-Cycle/set1/image1.jpg" alt="Image 1" width="180" height="150" onclick="HMimage1()">');
document.write('<img src="JQuery-Cycle/set1/image2.jpg" alt="Image 2" width="180" height="150" onclick="javascript:location.href=\'mailto:gulfdriveband@gmail.com\'" style="cursor:pointer;">');

document.write('</div>');
```

Comment: I don't see an "onclick command" in the code you posted.  You should use a `click` event and bind it to you  `<img>` tag (perhaps by id).  You can then call multiple functions inside your click event function.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript/Jquery

```
function change() {
    var url = "https://www.google.com";
    window.open(url);
    window.location.href = "mailto:address@dmail.com";
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#img1').on("click", function() {
        change();
    });
})
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>

<img id="img1" src="" height="50px" width="50px" style="background-color:red">
```

`window.open` will open a new tab and change to a new page.
`window.location.href` will change the current page and by putting `mailto:` inside it pulls up the email box.